# Python non-greedy regexes

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

How do I make a python regex like `"(.*)"` such that, given `"a (b) c (d) e"` python matches `"b"` instead of `"b) c (d"`?

I know that I can use `"[^)]"` instead of `"."`, but I'm looking for a more general solution that keeps my regex a little cleaner. Is there any way to tell python "hey, match this as soon as possible"?

Answer (score 386, accepted):

You seek the all-powerful `*?`

From the docs, [Greedy versus Non-Greedy](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy)

> the non-greedy qualifiers `*?`, `+?`, `??`, or `{m,n}?` [...] match as *little*
>   text as possible.

Comment: According to the Internet Archive, all that link pointed to was a copy of the Python "re" module docs, so Trey's link works just as well.

Comment: This is called **"non greedy"** qualifier

Answer (score 92):

```
>>> x = "a (b) c (d) e"
>>> re.search(r"\(.*\)", x).group()
'(b) c (d)'
>>> re.search(r"\(.*?\)", x).group()
'(b)'
```

[According to the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> The '`*`', '`+`', and '`?`' qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much text as possible. Sometimes this behavior isn’t desired; if the RE `<.*>` is matched against '`<H1>title</H1>`', it will match the entire string, and not just '`<H1>`'. Adding '`?`' after the qualifier makes it perform the match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as few characters as possible will be matched. Using `.*?` in the previous expression will match only '`<H1>`'.

Comment: I tried a different one, and it is always so greedy:  
`>>> re.search("\(.+?$", x).group()   `    
`'(b) c (d) e'   
 `  
I expect the last ( to the end of the line, but it gives the first ( to the end of the line. Any suggestion on how to explain this, and how to achieve "the last ( to the end of the line"?

Comment: .*\(.*?\) should skip everything before the last (

Answer (score 17):

Would not `\\(.*?\\)` work? That is the non-greedy syntax.

Answer (score 8):

Using an ungreedy match is a good start, but I'd also suggest that you reconsider any use of `.*` -- what about this?

```
groups = re.search(r"\([^)]*\)", x)
```

Answer (score 7):

Do you want it to match "(b)"?  Do as Zitrax and Paolo have suggested.  Do you want it to match "b"?  Do

```
>>> x = "a (b) c (d) e"
>>> re.search(r"\((.*?)\)", x).group(1)
'b'
```

Answer (score 6):

As the others have said using the ? modifier on the * quantifier will solve your immediate problem, but be careful, you are starting to stray into areas where regexes stop working and you need a parser instead.  For instance, the string "(foo (bar)) baz" will cause you problems.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, I do not suggest using "*" in regexes. Yes, I know, it is the most used multi-character delimiter, but it is nevertheless a bad idea. This is because, while it does match any amount of repetition for that character, "any" includes 0, which is usually something you want to throw a syntax error for, not accept. Instead, I suggest using the `+` sign, which matches any repetition of length > 1. What's more, from what I can see, you are dealing with fixed-length parenthesized expressions. As a result, you can probably use the `{x, y}` syntax to specifically specify the desired length.

However, if you really do need non-greedy repetition, I suggest consulting the all-powerful `?`. This, when placed after at the end of any regex repetition specifier, will force that part of the regex to find the least amount of text possible.

That being said, I would be very careful with the `?` as it, like the Sonic Screwdriver in Dr. Who, has a tendency to do, how should I put it, "slightly" undesired things if not carefully calibrated. For example, to use your example input, it would identify `((1)` (note the lack of a second rparen) as a match.