# python regular expression did not catch some field

Tags: python, html, regex

Hi all: I have a string

```
s2 = '[u\'\\n\', <td><a href="/etf/UVXY/">UVXY</a></td>, u\'\\n\', <td><a href="/etf/
       UVXY/">Ultra VIX Short-Term Futures ETF</a></td>, u\'\\n\', <td class="rightnobr">+7'
pat = re.compile('<a href=.+>(.+)</a>')
re.findall(pat,s2) only returns ['Ultra VIX Short-Term Futures ETF']..
```

why it can't catch the field ['UVXY']? if i do

```
s22 ='[u\'\\n\', <td><a href="/etf/UVXY/">UVXY</a></td>, u\'\\n\', <td><'
re.findall(pat,s2) did return ['UVXY']
```

Comment: This is a rather strange input data format, where is it coming from?

Comment: does the input string has two lines?

Comment: or, instead of using regex to match HTML, which all agree is a generally awful idea, why not use a parser like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)?

Comment: @alecxe http://etfdb.com/compare/volume/  don't worry guys. problem solved

Comment: @XunBao so this is an HTML you are parsing with regex. You should not do this, there are HTML parsers out there.

Comment: @alecxe i don't know. i used Beautifulsoup to deal with webpage first..

Comment: @XunBao I'm pretty sure you can extract the data without regex here. What is your desired output?

Comment: @alecxe i am building a simple local database, and collect [s&500][ndx100][etfs] symbols from different webiste. the way i did it is using beautifulsoup to clean up the website `File = urllib2.urlopen(item)`
`redditHtml = File.read()` `soup = BeautifulSoup(redditHtml)`, and then use re.findall or re.search to retrive all the symbols..

Comment: @XunBao ok, I've posted an answer with the code that retrieves all of the data from the table. Check it out. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` is a greedy operator, so `<a href=.+>` will capture `<a href="/etf/UVXY/">UVXY</a></td>, u\'\\n\', <td><a href="/etf/UVXY/">` and the rest will be captured by `(.+)`. That is why you are getting only `Ultra VIX Short-Term Futures ETF`. You need to make it non-greedy like this

```
pat = re.compile('<a href=.+?>(.+?)</a>')
```

**Output**

```
['UVXY', 'Ultra VIX Short-Term Futures ETF']
```

If you make only the first part as non-greedy, then `(.+)` will match everything till the last `</a>`. So, if the RegEx is

```
pat = re.compile('<a href=.+?>(.+)</a>')
```

then the output will be

```
['UVXY</a></td>, u\'\\n\', <td><a href="/etf/UVXY/">Ultra VIX Short-Term Futures ETF']
```

That is why you need to make both the greedy quantifiers as non-greedy, like in my first example.

Answer (score 1):

`.+` is greedy match. (`href=.+>` matches upto the last `>` that satisfy the rest of the pattern) Use non-greedy version: `.+?`.

```
>>> import re
>>> s2 = '[u\'\\n\', <td><a href="/etf/UVXY/">UVXY</a></td>, u\'\\n\', <td><a href="/etf/UVXY/">Ultra VIX Short-Term Futures ETF</a></td>, u\'\\n\', <td class="rightnobr">+7'
>>> pat = re.compile('<a href=.+?>(.+?)</a>')
>>> re.findall(pat,s2)
['UVXY', 'Ultra VIX Short-Term Futures ETF']
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766372/python-non-greedy-regexes Related Question

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your match is being **greedy** in which the pattern consumes maximum characters. Technically speaking, it's actually the quantifier `+` that is being greedy. To get a [non-greedy](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html) match, use `+?`

```
>>> pat = re.compile('<a href=.+?>(.+?)</a>')
>>> re.findall(pat, s2)
['UVXY', 'Ultra VIX Short-Term Futures ETF']
```

You may consider using a [tool](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for the job as well.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s2)
>>> links = [str(x.text) for x in soup.find_all('a')]
['UVXY', 'Ultra VIX Short-Term Futures ETF']
```

Answer (score 0):

[Do not use regex for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), use a specialized tool called HTML parser, like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'http://etfdb.com/compare/volume/'

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(URL))
for row in soup.select('table.msdata tr')[1:]:
    print [td.text.strip() for td in row('td')]
```

Prints:

```
[u'SPY', u'SPDR S&P 500', u'86,697,703', u'$172,868.1 M']
[u'EEM', u'iShares MSCI Emerging Markets ETF', u'46,298,734', u'$40,803.4 M']
[u'IWM', u'iShares Russell 2000 ETF', u'45,452,871', u'$25,882.6 M']
[u'QQQ', u'QQQ', u'35,422,355', u'$43,725.0 M']
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough StackOverflow *juice* to post a comment, so this appears as an answer.  I regularly use online RE parsers to experiment and test my REs.  Here is one of the better ones that also includes some good documentation: http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html