# Python-Delete anything in quotes from line in text file

Tags: regex, python-2.7, substring

I'm trying to remove any text inside of quotation marks (and the quotation marks themselves) from a file.

Basically I need this:

```
A A2A|"Dm"A2A "C"G2E|"Dm"D2D A,2D|
```

To turn into this:

```
A A2A|A2A G2E|D2D A,2D|
```

Here's a code snippet of what I originally tried:

```
def conversion():
    with open(abc + .'txt') as infile, open(abc + '.tmp', 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            #Delete anything inside of quotes after the header
            if '"' + '' in line:
                line = line.replace('"' + '', '')
                outfile.write(line)

            #Write everything else 
            else:
                outfile.write(line)
conversion()
```

This removes the quotation marks, but it leaves everything that was inside of them.

---

If I change

```
line = line.replace('"' +'','')
```

To

```
line = line.replace('"' + "Dm" + '"', '')
```

I can get rid of anything containing "Dm", theoretically I could program this for each possible combination, but that would be a huge PITA and I want to allow for human error (e.g. Someone wrote "Dma" instead of "Dmaj").

---

I've also tried using regex, but I honestly have no idea what I'm doing with it.

```
def conversion():
    with open(abc + '.txt') as infile, open(abc + '.tmp', 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            #Delete anything inside of quotes after the header
            if '"' in line:
                re.sub('".+"', '', line)
                outfile.write(line)

            #Write everything else 
            else:
                outfile.write(line)
conversion()
```

This seems to do nothing, I've looked through the python documentation, but there's no example to show how to use it in the context I'm trying to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.sub()` returns the edited line, it doesn't edit in-place.

```
line = re.sub('".*?"', '', line)
outfile.write(line)
```

And your regex would match across quotes, so I edited it to make it [non-greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/766384).

Comment: Thank you, if you don't mind another question, does it matter whether you use * or + in re.sub() ?

Comment: Yes it matters; `.*` matches "none or more characters", and `.+` matches "one or more characters".  So `".*"` will match an empty pair of quotes (`""`), whereas `".+"` will not match empty quotes, it needs to have at least one character inside the quotes.