# Regular Expression Findall Stopping Search in First Occur

Tags: python, regex, search, find, findall

I am trying to find a certain string with RegEx.
I want to find "something starting with 'f' and ending with first 2" (it must contain only one 2). In this example I want to find `result = "fdba12"` but the code at below is giving me `'fdba12312'` (containing two 2). How can I stop searching when I find 2 immediately?

```
import re
string2 = "asfdba12312 sssdr1 12şljş1 kf"

t = re.findall(r'[f][\w]*[2]', string2 )
print(t)
```

Comment: Related [Python non-greedy regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/766372)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your regex contains a `\w*` pattern that can also match the adjoining `2` pattern. There are 2 ways to achieve what you need: 1) using a lazy quantifier suggested by rock321987, and 2) use a reverse shorthand char class inside a negated character class `[^...]` and also negate `2`.

Thus, use

```
f[^\W2]*2
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jI9aL8/1)

The `[^\W2]*` pattern matches zero or more characters other than non-word characters (so, it matches all word characters) and those other than `2`.

Note: greedy matching is faster than lazy matching here.