# Proper Regex for Romans located at Ahead and Behind in Python

Tags: python

Following is the Raw-Text that I need to do *re.search* (stored in variable named 'table_t'):

**'                                  Table of Contents I.   INTRODUCTION          ....................................                                  1 II.  FACTUAL ASPECTS . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .     2      A.   The Clean Air Act . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  3      B.   EPA\'s Gasoline Rule . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    3           1.     Establishment of Baselines . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .      3           2.     Reformulated Gasoline . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .       4           3.     Conventional Gasoline (or "Anti-Dumping Rules") . . . . . . . .                 4      C.   The May 1994 Proposal . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .      5 III. MAIN ARGUMENTS . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .      5      A.   General          ....................................                                  5      B.   The General Agreement on Tariffs and Trade . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .             6           1.     Article I - General Most-Favoured-Nation Treatment . . . . . . .                6           2.     Article III - National Treatment on Internal Taxation                  and Regulation . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    7                  a)      Article III:4 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .   7                  b)      Article III:1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  14           3.     Article XX - General Exceptions . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .        15           4.     Article XX(b) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  15                  a)      "Protection of Human, Animal and Plant Life                          or Health" . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .   15                  b)      "Necessary" . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    15           5.     Article XX(d) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  21           6.     Article XX(g) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  22                  a)      "Related to the conservation of exhaustible natural                          resources..." . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  22                  b)      "... made effective in conjunction with restrictions                          on domestic production or consumption" . . . . . . . . . .             23           7.     Preamble to Article XX . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .     23           8.     Article XXIII - Nullification and Impairment . . . . . . . . . . . .           25 '**

I'd like to match ['I.INTRODUCTION ... 1' , 'II.FACTUAL ASPECT...2', 'III.MAIN ARGUMENT....5'] which are in a form of **'ROMAN + TITLE + DOTs + PAGE NUMBER'**

So I had written down code like this:

```
romans = ["I.", "II.", "III.", "IV.", "V.", "VI.", "VII.", "VIII.", "IX.", "X."]
for i in range(0,len(romans)):
    try:
        print(i)
        print(re.search(r"((?<={})(.*)(\d))(?!{})".format(romans[i], romans[i+1]),table_t).group())
    except:
        pass
```

But it keep returns like this:

**0
   INTRODUCTION          ....................................                                  1 II.  FACTUAL ASPECTS . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .     2      A.   The Clean Air Act . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  3      B.   EPA's Gasoline Rule . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    3           1.     Establishment of Baselines . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .      3           2.     Reformulated Gasoline . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .       4           3.     Conventional Gasoline (or "Anti-Dumping Rules") . . . . . . . .                 4      C.   The May 1994 Proposal . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .      5 III. MAIN ARGUMENTS . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .      5      A.   General          ....................................                                  5      B.   The General Agreement on Tariffs and Trade . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .             6           1.     Article I - General Most-Favoured-Nation Treatment . . . . . . .                6           2.     Article III - National Treatment on Internal Taxation                  and Regulation . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    7                  a)      Article III:4 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .   7                  b)      Article III:1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  14           3.     Article XX - General Exceptions . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .        15           4.     Article XX(b) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  15                  a)      "Protection of Human, Animal and Plant Life                          or Health" . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .   15                  b)      "Necessary" . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    15           5.     Article XX(d) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  21           6.     Article XX(g) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  22                  a)      "Related to the conservation of exhaustible natural                          resources..." . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  22                  b)      "... made effective in conjunction with restrictions                          on domestic production or consumption" . . . . . . . . . .             23           7.     Preamble to Article XX . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .     23           8.     Article XXIII - Nullification and Impairment . . . . . . . . . . . .           25
1
  FACTUAL ASPECTS . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .     2      A.   The Clean Air Act . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  3      B.   EPA's Gasoline Rule . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    3           1.     Establishment of Baselines . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .      3           2.     Reformulated Gasoline . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .       4           3.     Conventional Gasoline (or "Anti-Dumping Rules") . . . . . . . .                 4      C.   The May 1994 Proposal . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .      5 III. MAIN ARGUMENTS . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .      5      A.   General          ....................................                                  5      B.   The General Agreement on Tariffs and Trade . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .             6           1.     Article I - General Most-Favoured-Nation Treatment . . . . . . .                6           2.     Article III - National Treatment on Internal Taxation                  and Regulation . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    7                  a)      Article III:4 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .   7                  b)      Article III:1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  14           3.     Article XX - General Exceptions . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .        15           4.     Article XX(b) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  15                  a)      "Protection of Human, Animal and Plant Life                          or Health" . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .   15                  b)      "Necessary" . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    15           5.     Article XX(d) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  21           6.     Article XX(g) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  22                  a)      "Related to the conservation of exhaustible natural                          resources..." . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  22                  b)      "... made effective in conjunction with restrictions                          on domestic production or consumption" . . . . . . . . . .             23           7.     Preamble to Article XX . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .     23           8.     Article XXIII - Nullification and Impairment . . . . . . . . . . . .           25
2
 MAIN ARGUMENTS . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .      5      A.   General          ....................................                                  5      B.   The General Agreement on Tariffs and Trade . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .             6           1.     Article I - General Most-Favoured-Nation Treatment . . . . . . .                6           2.     Article III - National Treatment on Internal Taxation                  and Regulation . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    7                  a)      Article III:4 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .   7                  b)      Article III:1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  14           3.     Article XX - General Exceptions . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .        15           4.     Article XX(b) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  15                  a)      "Protection of Human, Animal and Plant Life                          or Health" . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .   15                  b)      "Necessary" . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    15           5.     Article XX(d) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  21           6.     Article XX(g) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  22                  a)      "Related to the conservation of exhaustible natural                          resources..." . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  22                  b)      "... made effective in conjunction with restrictions                          on domestic production or consumption" . . . . . . . . . .             23           7.     Preamble to Article XX . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .     23           8.     Article XXIII - Nullification and Impairment . . . . . . . . . . . .           25
3
4
5
6
7
8
9**

There's too many tails attached after the page number of corresponding page numb for given roman alphabet appears.

Which point went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [non-greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766372/python-non-greedy-regexes) regex while matching for the  **TITLE + DOT(S)**

```
import re

table_t = """' Table of Contents I. INTRODUCTION .................................... 1 II. FACTUAL ASPECTS . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 2 A. The Clean Air Act . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 3 B. EPA\'s Gasoline Rule . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 3 1. Establishment of Baselines . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 3 2. Reformulated Gasoline . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 4 3. Conventional Gasoline (or "Anti-Dumping Rules") . . . . . . . . 4 C. The May 1994 Proposal . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 5 III. MAIN ARGUMENTS . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 5 A. General .................................... 5 B. The General Agreement on Tariffs and Trade . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 6 1. Article I - General Most-Favoured-Nation Treatment . . . . . . . 6 2. Article III - National Treatment on Internal Taxation and Regulation . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 7 a) Article III:4 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 7 b) Article III:1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 14 3. Article XX - General Exceptions . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 15 4. Article XX(b) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 15 a) "Protection of Human, Animal and Plant Life or Health" . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 15 b) "Necessary" . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 15 5. Article XX(d) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 21 6. Article XX(g) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 22 a) "Related to the conservation of exhaustible natural resources..." . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 22 b) "... made effective in conjunction with restrictions on domestic production or consumption" . . . . . . . . . . 23 7. Preamble to Article XX . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 23 8. Article XXIII - Nullification and Impairment . . . . . . . . . . . . 25 '"""
for i in range(0, len(romans)):
    try: #\s+ : one or more white spaces(re.s) 
         #[] bracket denotes character group 
         #* preceding one could be matched multiple times 
         #\. means real dot(literally dot!)
        print("{}th trial - for roman {}".format(i,romans[i]))  
        print(re.search(r"((?<={})\s+(?P<name>[A-Z \.]*?)(\d))".format(romans[i]), toc).group())
    except:
        pass
```

Output :

```
0th trial - for roman I.
   INTRODUCTION          ....................................                                  1
1th trial - for roman II.
  FACTUAL ASPECTS . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .     2
2th trial - for roman III.
 MAIN ARGUMENTS . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .      5
3th trial - for roman IV.
4th trial - for roman V.
5th trial - for roman VI.
6th trial - for roman VII.
7th trial - for roman VIII.
8th trial - for roman IX.
9th trial - for roman X.
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .     2
```

Here's the Output