# Python regular expression parentheses matching not returning the proper substring

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use python's re to match a certain format.

```
import re
a = "y:=select(R,(time>50)and(qty<10))"   
b = re.search("=.+\(",a).group(0)
print(b)
```

I actually want to select this portion`"=select("`from string a. but the code I have made outputs the answer as =select(R,(time>50)and(. I tried `re.findall`, but this too returns the same output. It does not notice the first match and only outputs the final match. Anywhere I'm going wrong? Your Help is greatly appreciated. I basically want to find the function name, in this case select. The strategy is used was appears after `=` and before `(`.

Comment: [Similar question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766372/python-non-greedy-regexes)

Comment: regex is "greedy" - it tries to find the longest matching string. Using `?` like in answer it tries to find the shortest string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing '?' in your pattern, try this:

```
=.+?\(
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qqzT0d/1)

Answer (score 2):

Another method that works - you specify explicitly what you need:

```
import re
a = "y:=select(R,(time>50)and(qty<10))"   
# make sure your piece does not contain "("
b = re.search("=[^\(]+\(",a).group(0)
print(b)
```