# Remove in side '(data)' in string python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, types

Remove in side '(data)' in string python, I have string like this "i am learning python programming, (Because) it is easy langue for new learner(s)" i want to remove first (Because) data only. In side (data) may vary anything. Not constant.

Comment: and also it is easy language for new learners(s). Thanks for your replay

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python non-greedy regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766372/python-non-greedy-regexes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "i am learning python programming, (Because) it is easy langue for new learner(s)"
>>> ''.join(re.split(r"\([^)]*\)", string))
'i am learning python programming,  it is easy langue for new learner'
```

The pattern searches for opening brace, then any stuff except closing brace, then closing brace.

Comment: Hmm, why not use replace?

Comment: Sorry for that, Inside brackets may vary any data not exactly (Because).

Comment: @Vicrobot.@nick Thank you so much, It is work for me.

Comment: @Vicrobot I have one doubt sir, Can we get inside parenthesis data, It may varies anything like above.

Comment: @SaikumarKshatriya   Instead of re.split, use re.findall then.