# pythonic way for finding all the placeholders in a string

Tags: python, regex, substring

I have a string, which contains placeholders, surrounded by "%".  I want to get a list of those placeholders.  I tried this regex

```
m = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % ('\%', '\%'), message)
```

on the following string

```
black %brown% fox jumped over the %lazy% dog
```

I expect to get

```
['brown', 'lazy']
```

but instead, I get

```
'brown% fox jumped over the %lazy'
```

Comment: You have a greedy search though jumping right to the last `%`. Question: Does your strings hold any other `%` other than the placeholders?

Comment: Similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766372/python-non-greedy-regexes

Comment: Why are you using string formatting at all? `'%(.*)%'` is a valid regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
text =" black %brown% fox jumped over the %lazy% dog"
print(re.findall(r'%(.*?)%', text))
```

Comment: thank you @toRex.  Even though the other answers are correct also, I decided to accept yours, because it is the shortest, thus the most elegant.

Answer (score 0):

By default, searches are made in greedy mode: it will try to find the longest matching text.

You have two solutions:

- Perform a non-greedy search (as pointed out by JvdV and xdhmoore in the comment section), add a `?` next to the `*`: `(.*?)`
- Edit your regexp to forbid any `%` inside the placeholder, using `[^%]` instead of `.`:

  ```
  m = re.search('%([^%]*)%', message)
  ```

---

***Note:** I removed the percentage string formatting. I believed you wanted to parametrize the placeholder boundary, but now I likely share the opinion of chepner, I removed it and wrote in place plain regex.*

Comment: There's no need for the `%` operator; `'%([^%]*)%'` is fine.

Comment: @chepner, OP seems to have parametrized the placeholder bounday.

Comment: No, the OP seems to think that `%` is special in *any* string, not just one used as the left-hand operand of the `%` operator.

Comment: @chepner, I think you're right about OP intentions. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a regular experssion to find a item which is inbetween to `%` sings.

```
'%(\w+)%'
```

Afterwards your should use

```
string ='black %brown% fox jumped over the %lazy% dog'
m = re.findall(r'%(\w+)%', string)
print(m)
```

Comment: thanks! what's the difference between (.*?) and (\w+) ? why is one better than the other?

Comment: I can not tell you what is better, but `\w+` matches only word characters. `(.*?)` matches any symbol, even non-letters. In your example you did have only letters between the `%` signs. So I thought it would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `?` after the modifier the get a non-greedy search -

```
re.findall('%s(.*?)%s' % ('\%', '\%'), message)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
message ='black %brown% fox jumped over the %lazy% dog'
m = re.findall(r'%(.*?)%', message)
print(m)
```

Output:-

```
['brown', 'lazy']
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Solved]:** Using Regex

```
import re

# Store your string
my_str = 'black %brown% fox jumped over the %lazy% dog'

# Find matches
match = re.findall('%([^%]*)%', my_str)

# Print everything
print match

# Iterate
for item in match:
    print item
```

[image]

**[Result]:**

> `['brown', 'lazy']`

Comment: You don't have to escape the `%`; it has no special meaning in a regular expression.