# python3 regular expression not limiting replace to first count only

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Friends: (Revised question)

Thank you in advance for your time and attention.

```
import re

txt = "ear_name:zebra-wow-ear:-:4"
x = re.sub(".*:", "", txt,1)
print(x)
```

I was **expecting** the output to

> zebra-wow-ear:-:4

removing

> ear_name:

from

> ear_name:zebra-wow-ear:-:4

but what I am **getting** is

> 4

What am I doing wrong ?

Please help.

-N

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python non-greedy regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766372/python-non-greedy-regexes)

Comment: You can use `x = re.sub(r"^[^:]*:", "", txt)`

Answer (score 0):

[Answer to the updated question]

You can try this:

```
x = re.sub(r".*?:", "", txt, 1)
```

which will do a non-greedy pattern match.

Alternatively, try:

```
x = re.sub(r"[^:]*:", "", txt, 1)
```

Both will replace the everything up to (and including) the **first** colon (`:`).

Note also the 4th argument is redundant in both cases, so you can also remove it and it should work.