# Including newline character with any other character in regex - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, jupyter-notebook

I am currently using Jupyter Notebook and Regex in Python to create a Word and Definition dictionary from a txt format dictionary file.

Sample data from text file:
`` ABACINATE\nA*bac"i*nate, v.t. Etym: [LL. abacinatus, p.p. of abacinare; ab off +\nbacinus a basin.]\n\nDefn: To blind by a red-hot metal plate held before the eyes. [R.]\n\nABACINATION\nA*bac`i*na"tion, n.\n\nDefn: The act of abacinating. [R.]\n\n ``

The pattern I am trying to create includes getting all capital letters for the word, followed by removing the text up until the definition.

Desired output

```
{'word': 'ABACINATE', 'definition': To blind by a red-hot metal plate held before the eyes.'}
{'word': 'ABACINATION', 'definition': The act of abacinating.'}
```

The pattern I have already tried is

```
pattern="""
(?P<word>[A-Z*]{3,}) #retrieve capital letter word
(\n.*\n\n\Defn:) #ignore all text up until Defn:
(?P<definition>\w*) #retrieve any worded character after Defn:
(.\ ) #end at the full stop and space
"""
for item in re.finditer(pattern,all_words,re.VERBOSE):
    print(item.groupdict())
```

I'm struggling to deal with the newline characters here. I have tried to isolate the capital letter, then start at the newline character immediately after and ignore any character up until the two newline characters before 'Defn:' and retrieve the definition ending at the full stop.

Is there a way to deal with newline characters in this way?

Comment: I would argue that this is not a good application for regular expressions.  You have specific search strings in a specific order.  Just grab through a '\n' for the word, then `str.find("Defn:",i)` to search for Defn from that point.

Answer (score 0):

You mostly had it, just missing a [non-greedy match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/766377/1717828) and an expanded set for the characters in the definitions.

```
import re
all_words = """ABACINATE\nA*bac"i*nate, v.t. Etym: [LL. abacinatus, p.p. of abacinare; ab off +\nbacinus a basin.]\n\nDefn: To blind by a red-hot metal plate held before the eyes. [R.]\n\nABACINATION\nA*bac`i*na"tion, n.\n\nDefn: The act of abacinating. [R.]\n\n"""

pattern="""
(?P<word>[A-Z*]{3,})([\s\S]*?Defn:)(?P<definition>[a-zA-Z -]*)
"""
for item in re.finditer(pattern,all_words,re.VERBOSE):
    print(item.groupdict())
```

> {'word': 'ABACINATE', 'definition': ' To blind by a red-hot metal
> plate held before the eyes'} {'word': 'ABACINATION', 'definition': '
> The act of abacinating'}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works, but does not include definitions that include other full stops, commas and quotations characters. Is there a workaround for the [a-zA-Z -]* part?

Comment: @beeslaw, I mean, there's lots of ways, but without you listing more desired input/output in the question I can only guess what you want.  For example, `(?P<word>[A-Z*]{3,})([\s\S]*?Defn:\ )(?P<definition>.+?\.(?= ))` does what you say but I don't know if it does what you want.

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you so much!