# is it possible to regex out repeating substrings in a concatenated string?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

String=AUGACGCAUAACCGACGAUGCAGCGGGCAACUAA

I tried

```
re.findall(r'AUG\w*UAA',string)
```

this gives me

```
"AUGACGCAUAACCGACGAUGCAGCGGGCAACUAA"
```

i want answer to be

```
"AUGACGCAUAA"

"AUGCAGCGGGCAACUAA"
```

Comment: Use a [non-greedy quantifier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-6): `r'AUG\w*?UAA'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python non-greedy regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766372/python-non-greedy-regexes)